# Cuda optim for maxwell

Tags: cuda

I am trying to understand the [parallel forall post on instruction level profiling](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-7-5-pinpoint-performance-problems-instruction-level-profiling/). And especially the following lines in section **Reducing Memory Dependency Stalls**:

> NVIDIA GPUs do not have indexed register files, so if a stack array is accessed with dynamic indices, the compiler must allocate the array in local memory. In the Maxwell architecture, local memory stores are not cached in L1 and hence the latency of local memory loads after stores is significant.

I understand what **register files** are but what does it mean that they are not **indexed**? And why does it prevent the compiler to store a stack array accessed with dynamic indices?

The quote says that the array will be stored in local memory. What block does this **local memory** correspond to in the architecture below?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> ... what does it mean that they are not indexed

It means that indirect addressing of registers is not supported. So it isn't possible to index from one register (theoretically the register holding the first element of an array) to another arbitrary register. As a result the compiler can't generate code for non static indexing of an array stored in registers.

> What block does this local memory correspond to in the architecture below?

It doesn't correspond to any of them. Local memory is stored in DRAM, not on the GPU itself.

Comment: "local memory" == "thread-local memory", a subset of global memory with per-thread address mapping.